# Qt - assembly code listview

Tags: c++, c, windows, qt, assembly

I need to create a listview for some asm code in Qt.

The problems are:

- The asm file is huge and I can't load it into a QPlainTextEdit widget or similar because that would hang up the application and would be terribly slow to scroll into
- A scrollbar should allow forward navigation (and this should be simple) but backwards navigation as well (and how can I disassemble previous instructions? I don't know how many bytes they have!)
- A "goto address" functionality would be hard to do even if I'm sure that the address corresponds to an instruction (and doesn't fall in the middle of one), the problem is the same of the previous point: I don't know the number of bytes of the instructions before it so I can't disassemble backwards for a few lines

Can somebody help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't load entire files into widgets/controls. Load only enough to show (e.g. 50 lines or whatever fits on the screen) and either cache the rest or use file mapping to quickly access other lines when needed.

As for disassembling backwards, you may try starting to disassemble at some distant point from the current position, e.g. at current address - 256 bytes. If you're disassembling code, the disassembly will likely synchronize within those 256 bytes. If there's data embedded into the code then, well, that's about the best you can do other than trying to go back a different number of bytes or to the beginning of the file.